# Adding Devise to Existing App - undefined method `sign_in' for #<OmniAuth::Strategies::Standard>

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, ruby-on-rails-5

I am adding Devise to an existing application. The authentication file is inside lib/omniauth/strategies/standard.rb. There is also multiple lib/omniauth/strategies/clientname_saml.rb files for the app (one per Apartment tenant). Due to the current sprint, I'd like to add Devise gradually and thus keep the current `user.authenticate` method. We're using a number of gems which automatically recognize the @current_user which Devise sets.

I've tried adding `sign_in(:user, user)` in the `callback_phase` below, but I get the error: `` NoMethodError (undefined method `sign_in' for #<OmniAuth::Strategies::Standard>) ``

```
module OmniAuth
  module Strategies
    class Standard
      include OmniAuth::Strategy
      include Rails.application.routes.url_helpers

      def request_phase
        if strategy_supported?
          redirect(new_session_path(request.params))
        else
          fail!('strategy_unsupported')
        end
      end

      def callback_phase
        # binding.pry
        if strategy_supported?
          email = standard_params[:email] || ''
          user = User.find_by(email: email.downcase)
          if user && !user.locked? && user.authenticate(standard_params[:password])
            sign_in(:user, user)
            super
          else
            redirect(sessions_failure_path(safe_params))
          end
        else
          fail!('strategy_unsupported')
        end
      end

      private

      def standard_params
        request.params.symbolize_keys.slice(:email, :password)
      end

      def safe_params
        request.params.symbolize_keys.slice(:email, :code, :target)
      end

      def strategy_supported?
        Preference.get(:login_strategy) == 'standard'
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

I was able to solve it by using `include Devise::Controllers::Helpers`.